# My first column of a matrix is returning a weird symbol, and not the intended input

Tags: arrays, c, char

I'm new to C and I'm trying to do a simple program where the user inputs a sequence of strings and then it is printed again using Arrays, but the first column of the array always returns with a weird symbol. It's input is stopped using the symbol "#". Can someone find the solution to this problem?

The cmd looks like this:

```
Input the Sequence:
morning
hey
#
The sequences are:
   ♥
h e y

-----------------------
Process exited after 10.01 seconds with return value 0
Press any key to continue...
```

The code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int findnumber (char c, char ArrayAlfabeto[27], int Numeracao[26]);
char findchar (int c, char ArrayAlfabeto[27], int Numeracao[26]);

int main(){
    
    char exit, exit2 = '#';
    char ArrayChar[50];
    char ArrayIni[50] = {0};
    char ArrayCharFinal[50];
    char ArrayAlfabeto[27] = {"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"};
    int Numeracao[26] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26};
    int ArrayNumeroAlfabeto[110];
    int ArrayNumeroAlfabeto2[110];
    int ArrayReverse[110];
    int B=0, G=0,j, i, n, size = 0, size2 = 0, PosicaoPivo, PosicaoSucessor, Encontrou = 0, Pivo, Sucessor, contador;
    char ArrayStrings[G][51];
    int ArrayLength[G];
    
    //Asks for the input string
    printf("Input the sequences: \n");
   
    while((ArrayIni[0] != exit2)){
        
        scanf(" %s^\n", ArrayIni);
        if(ArrayIni[0] != exit2){
            size2 = strlen(ArrayIni);
            for(B;B<size2;B++){
                ArrayStrings[G][B] = ArrayIni[B];
            }
            ArrayLength[G] = B;
            
        }
        B=0;
        G++;
        //printf("Teste 1: %c\n", ArrayStrings[0][0]);
    }
    
    printf("The sequences are: \n");
    int U=0;
    for(U;U<=G;U++){
        int I = 0, contador = ArrayLength[U];
        for(I;I<contador;I++){
            printf(" %c", ArrayStrings[U][I]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: When you do the definitions `char ArrayStrings[G][51];` and `int ArrayLength[G];`, what is the value of `G`? What does your learning material say about arrays and array sizes?

Comment: G starts with the value 0 and increses as the user inputs new strings

Comment: @PedroPT F,  What do you think `scanf(" %s^\n", ArrayIni);` does?

Comment: Again, what does your learning material say about arrays and array sizes? Does it say anything that arrays of zero sized is allowed (it's *not*) or that arrays are dynamic and can be extended at will (they *can't*)? Please go back to whatever book or tutorial you're reading, or class you're taking, and take some more time to learn the basics before continuing.

Comment: PedroPT F, `for(B;B<size2;B++){` is suspicious.  Did you want `for(B=0;B<size2;B++){`?

Comment: I see the problem then, i have seen ways to dynamically alocate memory using malloc and such. What i want is a way to allow the user to input infinite amount of sequences until he writes down a "#"

Comment: @PedroPTF Allowing the user to  input infinite amount of sequence gives the user the opportunity to overwhelm system resources if code tries to save that.  A sane upper bound is prudent.  User input is evil.

Comment: I did not think about that actually , i will rewrite the code in a way to put a limit of inputs. Maybe will solve my problem!

Comment: A variable doesn't track changes in another variable. If you say `int x = 0; int y = x; x = 42;`, then `y` becomes `0` and stays `0`. It doesn't suddenly become `42`. If this is clear to you, then try to come up with a reason why array sizes should behave differently.